# Backtracking - problem with list updates in the recurrsive call

Tags: python, data-structures, structure, backtracking, recursive-backtracking

I was trying to solve **797. All Paths From Source to Target**  from `Leetcode`.
I thought of using Backtracking with recursion.
In the below code, the list `setOfPaths` is also getting updated when I pop from `path`.
I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```py
class Solution(object):
    def allPathsSourceTarget(self, graph):
        path=[]
        setOfPaths=[]
        path.append(0)
        self.backtrack(graph,0,len(graph)-1,path,setOfPaths)
        return setOfPaths
    
    def backtrack(self,graph,src,dest,path,setOfPaths):
        if(src == dest):
            setOfPaths.append(path)
        else:
            for node in graph[src]:
                path.append(node)
                self.backtrack(graph,node,dest,path,setOfPaths)
                path.pop(len(path)-1)  #BackTracking
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to append `path` to the `setOfPaths`, it do not really append the `path`'s data, but the reference to `path` or `path` variable itself is appended.
Because `setOfPaths` did not contain the data, it contained the variable, when you modified data inside variable, you would see `setOfPaths` also be modified.

To get rid of it, the simplest way is to store a copy of variable, so that you would not modified the data when you try to modify the "main" variable.

This piece of code should work

```py
if(src == dest):
    setOfPaths.append(path[:])
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Saved my day.. This worked. Initially it gave me an error saying list has no attribute 'copy'. Then i found out path[:] is similar to copy(path) or path.copy(). Then it worked fine !! Thanks again